# Find the distance of a node to the root in BST

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree, treenode

I would like to find the distance of a given node to the root in Linked List Binary Search Tree. I have the below code to calculate the height of the tree(`root.getHeightN()`), from root to leaf, but what I need is now to go from leaf to root.

```
public int getHeightN(){
                int l, r;

                if(this.left == null){
                    l = 0;
                }else{
                    l = this.left.getHeightN();
                }

                if(this.right == null){
                    r = 0;
                }else{
                    r = this.right.getHeightN();
                }

                if(r > l){
                    return 1+r;
                }else{
                    return 1+l;
                }
            }
```

Here is Node class:

```
protected class Node
{
    Key key ;
    Val val ;
    Node left , right ;
    Node ( Key key , Val val )
    {
        this.key = key ;
        this.val = val ;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to move towards the root, you'll have to store the parent of each node.

Comment: How can I move towards parent?

Answer (score 0):

I can put here concepts how to move on this.

As now you want to go from leaf to root , follow the below steps.

1.Traverse the tree till leaf node(without calculating height)

just check **if(ptr->next != null) ptr++;**

2.Once you reach leaf node , again traverse back by checking

**if(ptr(Parent))** //return TRUE if parent is present otherwise FALSE

**HeightCount++;**

3.In this way you will reach root node and then stop traversing.

4.The value of **HeightCount** is height of your tree(ie. Distance of node to root in BST).

Comment: If I implemented Next and Parent would be piece of cake I know ... but the problem is I dont have them in my implementation, I added my Node class to my question, I guess I should work on implementing the parent and next... thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have extra field in each node to store the parent information. If you just want to print the path from node(N) to root node, it can be done without having any field, otherwise you need to store the parent information in each node. You will have to traverse from root to node (N) and than start going upwards with information in the node about the parent node. Since you are traversing downwards to get to the node, calculation of height in other direction is not of much use :)